Xgboost custom objective function. How to modify the weights?
I have a custom objective function to xgboost:
def custom_objective(y_true, y_pred, x = 3000):

    pred_probs = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-y_pred))

    top_x_indices = np.argsort(pred_probs)[-x:]

    #array of weights: higher weights for top x instances
    weights = np.ones_line(y_true)
    weights[top_x_indices] = 10

    grad = (pred_probs - y_true) / (pred_probs*(1 - pred_probs))
    
    hess = (2 * pred_probs**2 - 3 * pred_probs + 1 + y_true - 2 * y_true * pred_probs) / (pred_probs * (1 - pred_probs))**2

    return grad * weights, hess * weights

The idea is to set the weight of the top3000 samples higher because only the top scores will be used in production.
The problem is that it assigns the same weight each time and the weight doesnt get updated upon building the next tree. How could I get the actual weight of the given simple during the training into the custom objective function? If I could do that then I could set the weight on the top3000 higher, like multiplying those weight by 10.
Thank you!
